# numpy list of matrices assign without reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've been having trouble implementing lists of numpy matrices, as assigning one to another, even with slicing, results in linked lists.
Concretely, the code -

```
import numpy as np
lst1 = [ np.eye(5), np.eye(5) ]
lst2 = lst1[:]
lst2[0][0][0] = 7
```

changes the value of lst1.

The only answers I've been able to find recommend slicing the list with `[:]`, but that doesn't seem to work in this situation.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Do you *really* want a python list of numpy arrays, or do you want a single multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Maybe a 3 dimensional array would serve me better, but I'm trying to implement a neural network and I frankly don't want to rework all the relevant code I've already written.

Comment: Doing `lst1 = np.stack([np.eye(5), np.eye(5)])` will let you do `lst2 = lst1.copy()` Alternatively you can `copy()` each item in your python list.

Comment: `alist[:]` makes a copy of the list, but the referenced objects are the same.  That's no big deal if the elements are numbers or strings.  But if they are mutable, like other lists, dicts, or in your case arrays, you need a `deep copy` if you want them to be independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to make a deep copy of the original array:

```
import copy 
list2 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
```